# [iOS][Charts] bug on x axis Grid on a Scatter Chart

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I'm using this awesome lib [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) (v2.3.0) on a iOS9 and swift 2.3 project.

I'm using a ScatterChart but I have an issue on the xAxis grid. I enable it, but I don't understand why there is no line on the last x value ( '15 min.' )

[image]

Thanks for you help !

PS: do you know how to remove the top Y line ( 100% one ) ?

PS 2: do you know how to remove the "0%" label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way.

I add an xVal after "15 min". And then I zoom in the chart to hide the last value.

and to be clean on the chart, I put userInteraction to false